# How do I select only the <body> element's background whitespace for a Javascript onclick callback?

Tags: javascript, html, callback, onclick

I need to create a callback that allows me to click or double click the background of my webpage, to return it to its default layout (thereby, closing and returning things so far affected by event callbacks). If I add an onclick callback to my <body> element, it is called whenever I click higher-level elements, not just on the background. So, it is available everywhere. How do I ensure that only the lowest-level element (i.e. the background whitespace) can call the reset function?

Comment: See [`Event#stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: @Pythongister: Depending on your requirement. You can use any of the technique that I have mentioned in my answer. Learn a bit about Event Delegation. This will help you in the long run as well :) This has many use cases !!!

Comment: Stopping event propagation isn't making a difference. I'm using D3 and am just running d3.event.stopPropagation() at the end of my d3.select('body').on() callbacks, but the callbacks are triggered whether I click the background or an element further up the tree. I tried the equivalent technique in JQuery, but the callbacks acted identically in both libraries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `event propagation stop technique`. So that you stop your event from going up the DOM tree.

One such method is `event.stopPropagation();`

Do also look `Event Delegation`, this may also help depending on your requirement.

> The idea is that if we have a lot of elements handled in a similar
> way, then instead of assigning a handler to each of them – we put a
> single handler on their common ancestor.
>
> In the handler we get `event.target` to see where the event actually
> happened and handle it.

In your case I believe You may require `Event Delegation technique` along with `stopPropagation`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have **2** elements **background** div and the **inner** div which will **contain** all the **content** of your **webpage**

```
<body>
  <!-- the clickable background -->
  <div class="background-container" onclick="reset()" id="background"></div>
  <!-- Your webpage -->
  <div class="webpage">
    <h3>This is your webpage</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS** - to make the background fullscreen

```
.background-container{
  background-color: #4158D0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  /* Use z-index to put the  background behind your webpage */
  z-index: 0;
}

.webpage{
  /* positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed). */
  position: absolute;
  
  /*setting the z-index to one to bring it to front*/
  z-index: 1;
}


h3{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

**Javascript** - to make the background clickable and run the function reset()
This function will be triggered when the background is clicked
you can edit the function to fit your purpose

```
function reset(){    
  var colors = ["#4158D0", "#C850C0", "#FFCC70"];
  document.querySelector('#background').style.cssText = `background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, ${colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]}, ${colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]}, ${colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]},${colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]},${colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]})`
}
```

For this demo the reset() function will change the background color
Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/Alemalohe/pen/MWjBwOd